# Create new column with most recent date

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have some trouble with a dataset I have in data.table. Basically, I have
2 columns: scheduled delivery date and rescheduled delivery date. However,
some values are left blank. An example:

```
Scheduled        Rescheduled
NA               NA
2016-11-14       2016-11-17
2016-11-15       NA
2016-11-13       2016-11-11
NA               2016-11-15
```

I want to create a new column, which indicates the most recent
date of both columns, for instance named `max_scheduled_date`. 
Therefore, if `Rescheduled` is NA, the `max_scheduled_date` should
take the value of `Scheduled`, whilst `max_scheduled_date` should
take the value of `Rescheduled` if `Scheduled` is NA. When both
columns are NA, `max_scheduled_date` should obviously take NA.
When both columns have a date, it should take the most recent one.
I have a lot of problems creating this and do not get the results I want.

The dates are POSIXct, which gives me some trouble unfortunately.

Can someone help me out?
Thank you in advance,
Kind regards,
Amanda

Answer (score 1):

As the question is tagged with `data.table`, here is also a `data.table` solution.

`pmax()` seems to work sufficiently well with `POSIXct`. Therefore, I see no reason to coerce the date columns from `POSIXct` to `Date` class.

```
setDT(DF)[, max_scheduled_date := pmax(Scheduled, Rescheduled, na.rm = TRUE)]
DF
```

> ```
>     Scheduled Rescheduled max_scheduled_date
> 1:       <NA>        <NA>               <NA>
> 2: 2016-11-14  2016-11-17         2016-11-17
> 3: 2016-11-15        <NA>         2016-11-15
> 4: 2016-11-13  2016-11-11         2016-11-13
> 5:       <NA>  2016-11-15         2016-11-15
> ```

Note that the new column is appended by reference, i.e., without copying the whole object.

#### Data

```
DF <- setDF(fread(
  "Scheduled        Rescheduled
NA               NA
2016-11-14       2016-11-17
2016-11-15       NA
2016-11-13       2016-11-11
NA               2016-11-15"
)[, lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct)])
str(DF)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ Scheduled  : POSIXct, format: NA "2016-11-14" "2016-11-15" ...
>  $ Rescheduled: POSIXct, format: NA "2016-11-17" NA ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both columns are `Date` class, we can use `pmax` to create the max of the dates for each row

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.Date) #change to Date class initially
df1$max_scheduled_date <- do.call(pmax, c(df1, na.rm = TRUE))
df1$max_scheduled_date
#[1] NA           "2016-11-17" "2016-11-15" "2016-11-13" "2016-11-15"
```

---

It can also be done with the `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_all(as.Date) %>%
    mutate(max_scheduled_date = pmax(Scheduled, Rescheduled, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the class of the dates is POSIXct, which gave me trouble using a max function...

Comment: @AmandaBovul  Then do `df1 %>% mutate(max_scheduled_date = pmax(as.Date(Scheduled), as.Date(Rescheduled)))`

Comment: I did what you said, but I get all NAs for max_scheduled_date.. I do not know what I am doing wrong! @akrun

Comment: @AmandaBovul  I can't reproduce the problem as once the POSIXct is converted to 'Date' class it worked well for me

Comment: @AmandaBovul  Can you start from the beginning again? .  Also, if you can post the dput of the example you showed in the post

Comment: I tried to change the POSIXct to date, but even if R said it works, the class of the columns remains POSIXct. Can you explain to me how you converted it?

Comment: @AmandaBovul  If you check the first piece of code `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.Date)`  (assuming you have only columns and that are `POSIXct`), it is assigning the converted class back to the original object.  Suppose if you do the conversion and doesn't change the object, it remains as such